# REF! error with copyTo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need only part of the spreadsheet to be copied. If I use copying by values, hyperlinks don't work in other cells(and in this one too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to:

1. First use `copyTo()` to copy-paste the desired range with the values-only option on.
2. Then use `getFormulas()` to get all the formulas from the original sheet.
3. Then loop through this array of formulas to get the array coordinates of each one that contains the `"=hyperlink"` string.
4. Each time you find a formula that contains `"=hyperlink"`, paste it to the destination range using `setFormula()`.

The following does that:

```
function hyperCopy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
      sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"),
      lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow(),
      lastCol = sheet1.getLastColumn(),
      range1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastCol),
      range2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastCol);

  range2.clear();
  range1.copyTo(range2, {contentsOnly:true});

  var formulas = range1.getFormulas();

  formulas.forEach(function(e, i) { // e for element, i for index
    e.forEach(function(f, j) {      // f neatly stands for formula

      if (f.toUpperCase().indexOf("=HYPERLINK") !== -1) {
        sheet2.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setFormula(f);
      }

    })
  })
}
```

Make sure to adjust the sheet names to your own.

Comment: You forgot about copying format and possibility to replace all ranges to "name of the sheet!" in references.

Comment: I really don't get it Why am I supposed to do all this manually? Why are there no google methods for this? I am disappointed and think I am not suited to be a programmer.

Comment: None of this should be done manually! Steps 1-4 are just a general idea for what your script could do.

Comment: If you want I can post an example script tonight (that is in 14 hours from now where I am). I understand your frustration, Google does not make it easy to do just this.

Comment: I would like to see it, because I want to see the right way, but I am not in urge and I am not sure I need It at all. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith I just edited my answer to include code that saves the `"=hyperlink"` formulas. In the comments, now you also mention that you would like to replace all ranges to "name of the sheet!" in references. Why? In the question you seemed content with just pasting values, as long as the links are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

When copying a range from one sheet to another, the REF! commonly occurs because the copied range include formulas that use relative references and the resulting references on the destination range aren't valid.

Let say that o B2 you have =A1, which means get the value from the cell positioned one cell up, one cell left. If you copy B2 to C3, the resulting formula will be =B2 but if you copy B2 to A1 the result will be REF! because A1 there isn't on the referred position, one cell up, one cell left.

The fix will depend on what your formulas are intended to do. Some times making the references absolute ($A$1) will work.

Comment: What if formula returns a multiple rows result?

Comment: @JohnSmith Try something like `={A1:B2}`. If you require further details post a new question.

Comment: Ups I missed the **if**, I'm sorry (I should use my glasses and drink more coffee). If a formula return multiple rows, the use of absolute references could work but, as I mentioned on the answer, it will depend on what the formulas are intended to do. If you will post a new question, please include a [mcve].